# How can I make a timer that gives me up to 3 decimal numbers?

Tags: nstimer

I have been trying to build a timer that gives you 0.000, but I am unable to do it.

```
-(IBAction)myMethod{
    countDown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/1000.0f target:self selector:@selector(flash) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

- (void) flash
{
    timeStart += 0.001f;
}
```

but when i do this the first decimal place becomes seconds instead of decimals. if I do:

```
  -(IBAction)myMethod{
    countDown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/1000.0f target:self selector:@selector(flash) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

- (void) flash
{
    timeStart += 0.01f;
}
```

I only get 2 decimal places.

Any help on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSTimer *_timer;
    float _startTime;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (void)flash:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _startTime = 0.0f;
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/1000.0f
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(flash:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
}

- (void)flash:(NSTimer *)timer {
    _startTime += 0.001;
    NSLog(@"_startTime=%.3f", _startTime);
}

@end
```

Output:

```
2013-10-05 10:03:36.330 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=0.001
2013-10-05 10:03:36.331 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=0.002
2013-10-05 10:03:36.332 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=0.003
...
2013-10-05 10:03:37.609 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=0.999
2013-10-05 10:03:37.611 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=1.000
2013-10-05 10:03:37.612 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=1.001
2013-10-05 10:03:37.612 TimerTest[86869:303] _startTime=1.002
```

However note that you cannot guarantee that the timer has actually fired every 0.001 seconds so you should be calculating your incrementing time using a different clock mechanism, for example saving the start time as an absolute time and when the method is fired measuring the difference.